# Docusign oauth flow: which one can i use for my expample

Tags: docusignapi

i need to sing to my new customers a document with two options : 
- Document A : sent via email to be signed by the customer
- Document B : sent via email to be signed by the customer and his parent
I used for that the webhook and it work as well for demo version. My question is which oauth flow i have to use i hope you can provide an api example if possible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is who initiates the envelope? If it is an employee then auth code grant. If it is either the signer or an autonomous process (eg in reaction to an entry in a database) then JWT grant